# Do not see the option of Announcements in Chatter in a group

Tags: chatter

I am not able to see the option to use Announcements in a Chatter Group.
Has anybody used this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check that your environment is already upgraded to the spring 14 release. 
You can do that by checking on your homepage. There, you will see an orange button (top right) that either says "Discover Spring 14" or "Discover Winter 13". 
I assume it should already be spring 14 but just to be sure.

Then, you also need to check that you are either a system admin, a group owner or a group manager. Only those people can add these group announcements.

**UPDATE**

Also make sure that publisher actions are enabled. (chatter > settings)

Comment: Hey @Guddan , which of my suggestions in the end fixed your issue? And if it's fixed because of that please mark the answer as best answer.

Comment: Also make sure that publisher actions are enabled. (chatter > settings)  BTW where do I click to mark it as a best answer?

Comment: You have the up and down arrows left of each answer (as well as questions) you should use these to vote for them if you find it a good answer. You also get like a green tick under these arrows to mark an anwer as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below,

Under Salesforce Setup screen,

1.Type group layouts in quick find box

2.click the edit group layout

3.Under Mobile& Lightning Actions, drag and drog Announcement button to Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience and save it

Now refresh chatter page

Answer (score -1):

I checked in a DE (which is in spring14) and I don't see it, maybe you should ask Salesforce support to enable this option for you.

Comment: there's no need to ask Salesforce support (it's there out of the box). Have you checked the above suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I'm in a DE Spring14 and publisher actions ara enabled!

Comment: and you are a system admin or the owner or manager of the group? I just checked the following things at my end and I'm able to use these announcements.

Comment: Yes and I'm an Sys Admin and the owner of the groupe. and even checked the publisher layout and I don't have the component to add it

Comment: which publisher actions do you see if you go to chatter > groups > group layouts > edit the layout > then override the global publisher actions

Comment: Post, File, Link, Poll and New (Account, contact, case ...) log a call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14063/discussion-between-koenvm-and-melmoussaoui)